# can we use two SPFx extensions in one application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, spfx

I am pretty new SharePoint.
I would like to know if we can use two SPFx extensions in one application. Because i want the functionality of both field customizer and application customizer.
And if yes then how can we get the details of a selected file in a library using @pnp/sp.

```
sp.web.fields.getByTitle("Name").get().then((item)=>{
    console.log(item);
 });
```

Code used by me. But it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use two (or more) SPFx extensions in one SPFx project. Just run the `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` generator again, and it will give you the opportunity to add another extension (or web part, even) to the project.

To your second question, if you want to get a SharePoint file, you can use the File or Folder endpoints in @pnp/sp. [Here's some documentation.](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/files/) An example:

```js
sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/MySite/MyLibrary/MyFile.doc').get().then((file) => {
    console.log(file);
})
```